# Rich Snippet Image

Tags: rich-snippets

One of my pages is pulling the only image from the page and using it for a rich snippet in the Google results.  The image works for the page, but isn't the best for the search results.  I would have preferred it grabbed my favicon, but it isn't.

Short of replacing the image in the page, is there a good way to encourage Google to use a different image?

Comment: Do you have your page set up to specify a rich snippet for a preferred image? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#use-cases

Comment: @Steve, yes.  However, I didn't write it.  It was added via a WordPress plugin.  But the JSON does look to point to the correct image.